# Kafka - Singe producer-single consumer-multiple partition with only one copy

Tags: apache-kafka

I have started studying Kafka. Let consider the below context:

There is a topic. Only one producer brings in messages. The topic has three partitions. The replication factor is exactly one. I have a consumer group which has exactly one consumer. Round robin method is used to store messages by the cluster.

Is the above setup possible? I am getting contracting answers (answers are: the setup is possible where all data can be read without data loss AND the setup is not possible).

Since a consumer in a consumer group can read only one partition, the consumer can not read all the messages and hence the complete data can not be read?

Can someone please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you have described is absolutely possible.

A single producer can send messages to all three partitions in a round-robin fashion. This can, for example, be achieved if your messages do not have any keys.

Also, a single consumer is capable of reading multiple partitions within the same topic.
I guess you were confused by the fact that a single topic partitioncan only be consumed by one consumer within a consumer group. But that does not impact the other way around: one consumer reading multiple partitions.